# If checkbox is true I want to update the field on lead object. How to achieve this?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am displaying Opportunities on Lead custom Edit page if the owner is same.

Like below :

[image]

So my question is if any one of the checkbox is choosen it should display only that value. i.e if i choose checkbox one it should update text field with "TestOpp2" value.

Is it possible to do that?

Here is mycode :

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!oppz}" var="o">

  <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header" > Opportunity Name</apex:facet>
                    {!o.name}
                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column headerValue="Select">

                        <input type="checkbox" id="looped" onclick="enableDisable(this)" /></apex:column>      

</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Controller :

```
public class LeadandOpportunities {

    public List<Opportunity> oppz;
    public boolean IsChecked {get; set;}

    //public Opportunity op;
    public Lead lead; 
    public LeadandOpportunities (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        system.debug('##########################');

        this.lead= (Lead)controller.getRecord();
        IsChecked = false;
    }
    public List<Opportunity> getOppz()
    {
        Lead l = [Select id,Name,OwnerId FROM Lead where id =: this.lead.id];
        system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@' +l);

        if (l.OwnerId== null)
            return null;
        oppz = [Select id, Name, Account.Name,Select__c, CloseDate, Amount, Type from Opportunity where OwnerId =: l.OwnerId];
        System.debug('$$$$$$$' + oppz);
        return oppz;
    }
}
```

Comment: update what field? some field on Lead?  I'm unclear what you want to do in the database if a box is checked?

Comment: Some text text field on Lead

Answer (score 1):

Updated vf page

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!oppz}" var="o">

    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header" > Opportunity Name</apex:facet>
            {!o.name}
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column headerValue="Select">

        <input type="checkbox" id="looped" onclick="enableDisable(this), updateLead('{!o.id}')" />
    </apex:column>      

</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:actionFunction name="updateLead" action="{!updateLead}">
    <apex:facet name="oppId" value="" assignedTo="{!oppId}" />
</apex:actionfunction>
```

Updated class

```
Public String oppID {GET;SET;}

Public void updateLead(){

    //oppId vairable will have the selected opportunity id value
    //Do whatever you want to based on the selected opportunity here

}
```